# Why isn't "is not" working with ConfigParser.sections() in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, configparser

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('bindslash.ini')

print([name for name in config.sections() if name is not 'bindslash'])
```

`bindslash.ini` looks like this:

```
[bindslash]

[somethingelse]
```

Running this program produces `['bindslash', 'somethingelse']`. However, if I change the `is not` in the list comprehension to be `!=` instead, the program correctly produces `['somethingelse']`. As far as I understand it, these should be the exact same thing. Why isn't `is not` working?

I'm on Python 3.5.0, installed from Homebrew on OS X.

Comment: Try `print([name for name in config.sections() if name != 'bindslash'])`. `is not` is not `!=`.

Comment: `is` checks for object identity, not object equality. Two strings that are equal may or may not be the same object.

Comment: @KevinGuan yeah, I tried your version, and it worked. I couldn't figure out why. that's what the question was about :)